# Representations of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm slightly confused about representations of Simple functions. I take it that simple functions are of the form $\phi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k \chi_{A_k}(x)$ where $\chi$ is the indicator function and that $A_k$'s are measurable sets.

Now on building the theory of integration using simple functions, it appears that it is necessary to construct the canonical form of simple functions for a definition of the Lebesgue integral. (well that's how Stein does it).

But my question is, if $\phi$ is a simple function defined above where it is not in its canonical form, will writing it in its canonical form ensure that the resulting disjoint sets are measurable? Or is this tautological by definition??

I cannot seem to grasp this because subsets of measurable sets aren't necessarily measurable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that $A_1 \cap A_2 \ne \emptyset$, we may simply rewrite the sum to include the terms

$$a_1 \chi_{A_1 \setminus A_2} + (a_1 + a_2) \chi_{A_2 \cap A_1} + a_2 \chi_{A_2 \setminus A_1}$$

Now it *is* true that intersections and differences of measurable sets are measurable, so there's no problems.

Answer (score 7):

Assume $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a simple function. Then $f$ is a measurable function that takes only finitely many real values. Let $\{c_1,\cdots,c_n\}$ be the set of possible values of $f$. Define $A_i=\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)=c_i\}=f^{-1}\left(\{c_i\}\right)$. Then $A_i$'s are measurable and 
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{A_i}$$
These $A_i$'s are disjoint and their union is $\Omega$. Thus for every simple function $f$ I can choose such a representation such that the $A_i$'s form a partition of $\Omega$.